# Problems extracting text from link

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm extracting text from a website using the rvest package (R) and have problems getting the exact text I need.

From this link 
https://securityaffairs.co/wordpress/83620/breaking-news/emotet-targets-chile.html

I need to extract all the text from the hr.wp-block-separator including the brakes 
.

This is my code:

```
con <- url("https://securityaffairs.co/wordpress/83620/breaking-news/emotet-targets-chile.html", "rb") ##binary connection to URL

content <- read_html(con)

p <- html_nodes(content, "p") %>% html_text()
```

in lines 25 and 60 I get the following result:

```
[25] "Threat name: __Denuncia_Activa_CL.PDF.batMD5: 1e541b14b531bcac70e77a012b0f0f7fSHA1: 0ca0cd36fb4c9dfeb3e325a01cfb7b75413d1f81First submission: 2019-03-22 00:39:43"

[60] "Threat name: Integrity.exeMD5: 98172becba685afdd109ac909e3a1085SHA1: cbb0377ec81d8b120382950953d9069424fb100eFirst submission: 2019-03-18 15:10:08"
```

The MD5 hash gets collapsed with the word "SHA1" and the SHA1 hash gets collapsed with the word "First"

Ideally I would like to get 4 lines of text 1 attribute per line (Threat name, MD5, SHA1, First submission)

This is my code:

```
con <- url("https://securityaffairs.co/wordpress/83620/breaking-news/emotet-targets-chile.html", "rb") ##binary connection to URL

content <- read_html(con)

p <- html_nodes(content, "p") %>% html_text()
```

Actual output

```
"Threat name: __Denuncia_Activa_CL.PDF.batMD5: 1e541b14b531bcac70e77a012b0f0f7fSHA1: 0ca0cd36fb4c9dfeb3e325a01cfb7b75413d1f81First submission: 2019-03-22 00:39:43"
```

Expected Output

```
Threat name: __Denuncia_Activa_CL.PDF.bat

MD5: 1e541b14b531bcac70e77a012b0f0f7f

SHA1: 0ca0cd36fb4c9dfeb3e325a01cfb7b75413d1f81

First submission: 2019-03-22 00:39:43
```

Comment: May I know what is the difference between actual and expected outputs?

Comment: the MD5 hash gets collapsed with the word "SHA1" and the SHA1 hash gets collapsed with the word "First". I need titles separated from hashes

Comment: You can replace all `<br>` tags with a newline before parsing. Add ` xml_find_all(content, ".//br") %>% xml_add_sibling("p", "\n")` after `content <- read_html(con)`